# Assigning a function to an array of javascript buttons

Tags: javascript, html, loops

When I click on of these button I want an item in sessionStorage to be assigned to true which is indicative of the button which was pressed. When the fourth button is clicked I was it to show what information was selected to know more about.

Right now my button aren't returning anything and I can't figure out how to loop through this and assign a function to every button

```
//simple html to print four buttons.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Green Things</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="example.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
            <div><button id="moreAboutGrass" type="button" class="button">Send me more information about Grass</button></div>
            <div><button id="moreAboutMolluscs" type="button" class="button">Send me more information about Green Molluscs</button></div>
            <div><button id="moreAboutSweaters" type="button" class="button">Send me more information about Green Sweaters</button></div>
            <div> <button id="infoChosen" type="button" class="button">Things you want more information about </button></div>
            <div><output id = "output"></output></div>
    </body>

</html>

window.onload = function() {
//getting an array of all the buttons
    var y = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
//looping through all the buttons
    for(count = 0; count < y.length; count++){
             //Assigning an operation to the button
            document.getElementById(y[count].id).onclick = function(count) {
            //Assigning a variable to be the id name of button passed into this function
            z = y[arguments[i]].id;
            //If the button is the fourth button
            if ( z == "infoChosen" ){
            //Add in the things which were selected
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
                if (sessionStorage["moreAboutMolluscs"] == "true"){
                    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "Green Molluscs\n";
                }
                if (sessionStorage["moreAboutSweaters"] == "true"){
                    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "Green Sweaters\n";
                }
                if (sessionStorage["moreAboutGrass"] == "true"){
                    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "Grass\n";
                }
            }else{          
                //if the button was on of the first 3 just set a variable to true so it can be printed later
                sessionStorage.setItem(z, "true");
            }
        }
}
```

If the first button and then the fourth button is clicked the output should be

```
Green Molluscs
```

If the first and third button are clicked and then the fourth the output should be

```
Green Molluscs Green Sweaters
```

I need to do it in a loop

Comment: what's in `example.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Green Things</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        window.onload = function() {
            //getting an array of all the buttons
            var y = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
            //looping through all the buttons
            for(count = 0; count < y.length; count++){
                         //Assigning an operation to the button
                         var aa = y[count].id;
                         document.getElementById(y[count].id).onclick = function(aa) {
                            var  z = aa.currentTarget["id"];
                        if ( z == "infoChosen" ){
                        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
                        if (sessionStorage["moreAboutMolluscs"] == "true"){
                            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "Green Molluscs\n";
                        }
                        if (sessionStorage["moreAboutSweaters"] == "true"){
                            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "Green Sweaters\n";
                        }
                        if (sessionStorage["moreAboutGrass"] == "true"){
                            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "Grass\n";
                        }
                    }else{          
                            //if the button was on of the first 3 just set a variable to true so it can be printed later
                            sessionStorage.setItem(z, "true");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div><button id="moreAboutGrass" type="button" class="button">Send me more information about Grass</button></div>
    <div><button id="moreAboutMolluscs" type="button" class="button">Send me more information about Green Molluscs</button></div>
    <div><button id="moreAboutSweaters" type="button" class="button">Send me more information about Green Sweaters</button></div>
    <div> <button id="infoChosen" type="button" class="button">Things you want more information about </button></div>
    <div><output id = "output"></output></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it differently in this situation.
In my eyes the best option is to make a function for each button like this `<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>`and that function changes a variable too true or false. And when you click the 4th button it might be the best too use the switch statement for each possibility for the right output.

I am not that experienced in coding yet so this might not be the most efficient way but I hope this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, firstly, you're not accessing your `sessionStorage` correctly. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). And what you're doing looks a bit like a mess. I've tidied up the code in my answer below so I'll just make some explanations here.

- I decided to grab all your buttons using `document.getElementsByTagName("button");` it may not always be applicable, but it feels suitable in your case.
- I've changed using a for loop using length, to just using the `of` operator. It basically iterates through an array without needing to length it.
- I think the other parts concerning putting stuff into the sessionStorage is pretty straight forward, but if you are unsure, just ask me and I'll rewrite it.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ryvcvp42/